# Why the tables couldn't be migrated to database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I made a mini spring boot project.
My goal is to migrate tables to database.
But the tabled couldn't be migrated to database

I don't have any error in the terminal console but the tables couldn't be migrated

those are my dependencies in pom.xml
I added data jpa and mysql connector

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

this is application.propreties
I linked my database successfully

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_test?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=create
hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

this is my entity
should be migrated to database

```
package com.learn.demo.Model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private long id;

    @Column()
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private long code;

    @Column()
    private int views;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getViews() {
        return views;
    }

    public void setViews(int views) {
        this.views = views;
    }
}
```

this is the log

```
2023-07-02T11:30:10.017+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] com.learn.demo.DemoApplication           : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 28904 (C:\Users\Kessemtini\Desktop\projects\demo\target\classes started by Kessemtini in C:\Users\Kessemtini\Desktop\projects\demo)
2023-07-02T11:30:10.019+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] com.learn.demo.DemoApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-02T11:30:10.087+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-07-02T11:30:10.087+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-07-02T11:30:10.826+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-07-02T11:30:10.851+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 17 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-07-02T11:30:11.688+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-07-02T11:30:11.698+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-07-02T11:30:11.698+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.10]
2023-07-02T11:30:11.761+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-07-02T11:30:11.763+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1674 ms
2023-07-02T11:30:11.925+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-02T11:30:12.094+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@189b0459
2023-07-02T11:30:12.096+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-07-02T11:30:12.146+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-07-02T11:30:12.209+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.5.Final
2023-07-02T11:30:12.211+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-07-02T11:30:12.350+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-07-02T11:30:12.498+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-07-02T11:30:12.772+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-07-02T11:30:13.315+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-07-02T11:30:13.317+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-07-02T11:30:13.705+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-07-02T11:30:13.733+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-07-02T11:30:13.742+01:00  INFO 28904 --- [  restartedMain] com.learn.demo.DemoApplication           : Started DemoApplication in 4.168 seconds (process running for 4.683)
2023-07-02T12:07:14.601+01:00  WARN 28904 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=30m39s83ms799µs400ns).
```

this is the main app

```
package com.learn.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, add a no-args constructor to the entity class. Hope it helps. If not then share the main application class inclusive package definition and the application logs during startup.

Comment: @Mar-Z
I updated the question with logs and the main app

Comment: All looks good. However there is a typo in the application.properties. It should be: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

Comment: And a no-args constructor added to the entity class, right?

Answer (score 0):

use this entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
 public class Post {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;


@Column(name="code",unique = true)
private long code;

@Column(name="views")
private int views;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(long code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public int getViews() {
    return views;
}

public void setViews(int views) {
    this.views = views;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Post [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", code=" + code + ", views=" + views + "]";
}

public Post() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}